# Knockout Mapping Plugin to show data in a table

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have data coming from JSON as:

```
[
  {"ProjectName":"Region1.Site1","Turbine":"T1","Fault":0,"Description":"No Fault"},
  {"ProjectName":"Region1.Site1","Turbine":"T2","Fault":0,"Description":"No Fault"},
  {"ProjectName":"Region1.Site1","Turbine":"T3","Fault":1,"Description":"In Alarm"},
  {"ProjectName":"Region1.Site1","Turbine":"T4","Fault":1,"Description":"In Alarm"},
  {"ProjectName":"Region1.Site2","Turbine":"T1","Fault":0,"Description":"No Fault"},
  {"ProjectName":"Region1.Site2","Turbine":"T2","Fault":0,"Description":"No Fault"},
  {"ProjectName":"Region1.Site2","Turbine":"T3","Fault":1,"Description":"In Alarm"},
  {"ProjectName":"Region1.Site2","Turbine":"T4","Fault":1,"Description":"In Alarm"}
]
```

I would like to show this data into a table with table headers as `Project Name`, `Turbine`,  `Fault`, `Description`.

I am using Knockout.js and the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) as well. Here's a [JSFiddle to show what I tried so far](http://jsfiddle.net/WaQJp/1/).

I have mainly two goals

1. Put this data into table
2. Update the row whenever the Fault status changes. Each row is uniquely identified by combination of ProjectName and Turbine.

---

Thanks Sandeep.

I am having problem with this statement where I try to using mapping plugin.

`var viewModel = {};`

`viewModel.Stats = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);`

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong. Also when I receive updates in data, does the following statement work ?

`ko.mapping.fromJS(data,viewModel);`

Since the mapping plugin was not working , I had to use ko.utils.Arraymap function.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working copy. [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/WaQJp/3/)

Code was broken - no matching braces and reference to 'Data' instead of Stats.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some extra brackets and parentheses (after your data json definition and after *applyBindings*).  Other than that, you just need to change "foreach: Data" to "foreach:Stats" so that your *tbody* will point the viewModel's data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what I am doing which is virtually the same thing:

```
var UserRecord = function (data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
};

var mapping = {
    key: function (data) {
        return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.Id);
    },
    create: function (options) {
        return new UserRecord(options.data);
    }
};


function UserListViewModel() {
     this.users = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping)
}
```

The reason it wasnt working is since you have an array you have to tell KO mapping that each property in each array item needs to be an observable.